# Magento2 - product collection category anchor filter

Tags: magento2, product-collection

to filter products by certain category following code sample is used

```
<?php

$collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addCategoryFilter($category);

return $collection;
```

This does not return products from sub categories even though all categories are marked "Is Anchor" => "Yes".

How can I retrieve products from given category and it's sub-categories based on "Is Anchor" functionality?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out. Turns out there is a method [getAllChildren()](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Category.php#L765) that returns category ID along all sub-category IDs.

So to wrap it up:

```
$categoriesFilter = [
    'eq' => $category->getAllChildren(true)
];
$collection->addCategoriesFilter($categoriesFilter);
```

Comment: Where do you get the `$collection` variable from?

Comment: This works well but for completeness, and for other people reading this answer the $category object needs to be instantiated from the CategoryFactory to load your required category ID in order to pass the child array to the filter. See here for more info on loading $category https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96177/magento-2-get-product-collection-using-category-id

Comment: Some how it helps me today not same issue but your solution lead to me different solution that help me solve my problem