# Module created gives Error filtering template: {Classname} does not implement BlockInterface

Tags: magento2, module, blocks, magento-2.0, magento-2.0.7

I need a way to show products from a category and created a module following the advice of this answer of Marius (https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/146/marius) here: [Magento 2: get product collection using category id](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96177/magento-2-get-product-collection-using-category-id)

I did create a new module though with these files:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    '{Company}_GetProductCollection',
    __DIR__
);
```

as registration.php in app/code/{Company}/GetProductCollection

Then

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="{Company}_GetProductCollection" setup_version="1.0.0"></module>
</config>
```

as module.xml in in app/code/{Company}/GetProductCollection/etc and

```
<?php

namespace {Company}\GetProductCollection\Block;

class CeloGetProductCollection
{

  protected $categoryFactory;

  public function __construct(

      \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
  ){

      $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;

  }

  public function getCategory()
  {
    $categoryId = $this->getCategoryId();
    $category = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
    return $category;
  }

  public function getProductCollection()
  {
    return $this->getCagetory()->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
  }

}
```

as CeloGetProductCollection.php in app/code/{Company}/GetProductCollection/Block

I registered the module successfully with setup:upgrade.

Then bound the file into the page Home Page with:

```
{{block class="{Company}\GetProductCollection\Block\CeloGetProductCollection" category_id="15" template="Magento_Theme::html/discover_news.phtml"}}
```

and discover_news.phtml is in my theme directory. Having this content:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
?>
<?php foreach ($this->getProductCollection() as $product) : ?>
    print_r($product,true);
<?php endforeach;?>
```

What's missing? Because I get the page but instead the oroduct info I get:

> Module created gives Error filtering template:
>   {Company}\GetProductCollection\Block\CeloGetProductCollection does not
>   implement BlockInterface

Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: I now know how to access most items like:
`echo $product->getName() . ' # ' . $product->getProductUrl() . ' # ' . $product->getPrice(). ' # ' . $product->getDescription() . ' # ' . $product->getFormatedPrice() . ' # ' . $product->getData('small_image') . '<br />';`

Answer (score 6):

The problem is caused by the fact that **your block does not extend a Magento native block.**

You need to update your block code like this:

```
<?php

namespace {Company}\GetProductCollection\Block;

class CeloGetProductCollection extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

  protected $categoryFactory;

  public function __construct(
      \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
      \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
      array $data = []
  ){
      $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
      parent::__construct($context, $data);
  }

  public function getCategory()
  {
    $categoryId = $this->getCategoryId();
    $category = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
    return $category;
  }

  public function getProductCollection()
  {
    return $this->getCategory()->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
  }

}
```

On top of that you made a typo `getCagetory` instead of `getCategory`

Comment: Thanks alot for your fast answer. I saw classes in magento before that did not extend another class so I thought it will be ok. But it makes sense that this class gets extended. I will see if it get's solved and let you know. :)

Comment: When adding the changes I got the php-error "Fatal error: Call to a member function getProductCollection() on null in /var/www/clients/client170/web1213/web/app/code/{Company}/GetProductCollection/Block/CeloGetProductCollection.php on line 29"
I tried what happens when I put in return $this->getCategory(); in function getProductCollection() and it seems the function GetCategory() can successfully receive the cat ID but the $category var is empty then.
echo gettype($this->getProductCollection()); in .phtml shows it's an object.
Don't know how to handle this yet.

Comment: @Magento2Noob because your wrote `getCagetory` instead of `getCategory`

Comment: Good find. :D I wonder why netbeans didn't label this already as a typo.
Though now, after changing my template to:
`<?php foreach ($this->getProductCollection() as $product) :
    print_r($product,true);
  endforeach;?>`
I get a blank home page and no related error in system.log.
`print_r((array)$product,true);` does not help and `echo gettype($product);` make the page appear again and it shows objectobject, because 2 products are in this category. So it seems to work generally, only it does give back an object and I do not know how to handle it....

Comment: @Magento2Noob using `print_r` to display massive object like products is not recommended as it often ends up in memory exhaustion. I suggest you use xDebug to debug that instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I will see how I can find out how to handle that object...

Comment: I would upvote your answer but I can't register, or better I registered already but stackexchange seems to be unable to handle email addresses that contain a "-". And I can't complain in meta since out of all subforums especially the forum that would be the place for such complaints, is registered users only. ::)

Comment: @Magento2Noob you don't need to upvote you can simply mark your question as answered. You're probably logged in as you posted a question

Comment: Hey @Raphal at Digital Pianism, I do not see that I can change the question to anwered. And Iam not logged in. I'm writing as an unregistered user. I always have this message on top of the page that asks me to finish signing up.

Comment: @Magento2Noob well I managed to create an account and sign in with a "-" in my email address I reckon you could do the same

Comment: thanks for checking though when I want to register this new account with my normal email address it tells me that this email address is already in use. However, resending the password does not lead to me receiving an email. And I control the email server so nothing should vanish. Do you have contact to staff so I could give you my email address without making it public?

Comment: @Magento2Noob I suggest you should post that in http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/ and a moderator will take care of that. Ask the question by explaining clearly what your problem is